# SQL: Create a pilot report as shown below. HOW TO add the area code and the phone number in separate column

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table PILOT (
PILOT_NO             varchar2 (4),
NAME                 varchar2 (25),
ADDRESS              varchar2 (25),
CITY                 varchar2 (25),
PHONE                varchar2 (12),
TOTAL_HOURS                      number (7,2));


insert into PILOT values ('0001', 'Whiteknuckles, Harry', '9 Muddy Lane',
     'Swift Current', '306.911.1234', 0);

insert into PILOT 
values ('0002', 'Timson, Jean', '2302 - 67th St NE', 
    'Calgary', '403.288.1492',0);

insert into PILOT 
values ('0003', 'Lee, Wong', '17 Chester Place',
    'Calgary', '403.247.6543',0);

insert into PILOT 
values ('0004', 'Bedard, George', '7902 - 69 Ave', 
    'Saskatoon', '306.444.5555',0);

insert into PILOT 
values ('0005', 'Trachuk, Tony', '123 - 3rd St',
    'Saskatoon', '306.354.1234',0);

insert into PILOT 
values (
'0006', 'Paulson, Penny', '49 Gaetz Ave',
    'Red Deer', '403.356.4321',0);
commit;
```

| Pilo | Name | Area Code | Local Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | Whiteknuckles, Harry | 306 | 911.1234 |
| 0002 | Timson, Jean | 403 | 288.1492 |
| 0003 | Lee, Wong | 403 | 247.6543 |
| 0004 | Bedard, George | 306 | 444.5555 |
| 0005 | Trachuk, Tony | 306 | 354.1234 |
| 0006 | Paulson, Penny | 403 | 356.4321 |

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Function `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` is what you want:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(PHONE, '.', 1) as `Area Code`, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(PHONE, '.', -2) as `Local Number`
FROM PILOT;
```

Answer (score 0):

with this

```
ALTER PILOT
ADD COLUMN AreaCode INT,
ADD COLUMN AreaCode VARCHAR(12);
```